# UIToolbar: setItems and UINavigationController setToolbarItems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I got the following:

```
@interface A : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIToolbar *toolBar;
@end
```

Here the 'toolBar' property can be set from outside to point to a externally created UIToolbar OR it can point to the navigationController tool bar.

I want to set the tool bar items independent of witch tool bar 'toolBar' point's to.
I try the following without success:

```
    NSMutableArray *buttons = ...
    ...
    UIBarButtonItem *item = ...
    [buttons addObject:item];
    ...
//I know this are the same but...
    [self.toolBar setItems:buttons];
    self.toolBar.items = buttons;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

`[self.navigationController.visibleViewController setToolbarItems:@[button1, button2, button3]];`

Seems to work if you set the `ToolbarItems` on the `visibleViewController`.

Comment: This helped me! Why is the method also on `UINavigationController` and why do we need the method on `visibleViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into this issue because at least in the case where the `UINavigationController` is involved the toolbar items will be obtained from the `UIViewControllers` which are pushed onto the stack via their `toolbarItems` property.

EDITED after comment ...

What I'm saying is that you cannot do this:

```
self.toolBar = self.navigationController.toolbar;
self.toolBar.items = buttons;
```

When your view controller is within a UINavigationController you have to do:

```
self.toolbarItems = buttons; // OR [self setToolbarItems:buttons animated:YES];
```

Comment: But if I do: 'self.toolBar = self.navigationController.toolbar'. How can i manage the tool bar items?, the calls that i post in my question doesn't work

Comment: Post after edited: you are right, set the items of the UINavigationController's tool bar trough an UIToolbar reference doesn't work... I wonder why..